# How to get attachment files by current user in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, get, attachment

When users register to our platform, they have to upload file(s) to complete the registration. Those files are saved as attachments to the user's profile with the advanced field key: `user_registration_logo`

I have built a custom profile page for users and now I would like to show those uploaded files on that page. I think that the function.php has to be something like `get_user` & `get_attachment_url` and then with shortcode display files in UI.

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: Any thoughts on how to implement this one?

Comment: You using ACF? ...you mention the 'advanced field key' in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.